# How to test WCF services in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I've created a simple WCF application where I have added a display method in my service, but I don't know **how to test this display service?** I've searched using Google but didn't find any feasible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`WcfTestClient.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) utility which is part of the SDK. Another possibility is to write a sample client application in which you would import the service definition and be able to invoke its methods but it might be a little more work. As an alternative, if you are using a SOAP binding on your service you could also checkout [`SoapUI`](http://www.soapui.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The WCFTestClient is a good option, but it seems that VS2010 is somewhat inconsistent in launching it as a startup process. Best option is to run it from the VS2010 command line (as and administrator). You can also check out the free soapUI utility (http://www.soapui.org/)  which has (in my opinion) a much better interface and far more functionality than WcfTestClient

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, set the service as Startup project. This will lanch WcfTestclient.exe when you start run the debugger.